# Angular Material Custom tabs , manipulate using css , other solutions not working any updates happened?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

```
<mat-tab  aria-label="primary"></mat-tab>>
   <ng-template mat-tab-label  class="template-label">
      <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">message</mat-icon>
   </ng-template>
       Content 1
</mat-tab>

<mat-tab>
  <ng-template mat-tab-label >
    <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">person</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
       Content 2
</mat-tab>

<mat-tab >
  <ng-template mat-tab-label>
     <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">search</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
       Content 3
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

this is the code in html file , how to apply css on it , i tried encapsulating in ts file and multiple ways to change the css but not working

Answer (score 1):

here is how i targeted elements off the page and selecting it

```
::ng-deep .mdc-tab-indicator--active .mat-icon{
  background: #5dc3bd;
  color: #fff;

}
::ng-deep .mdc-tab-indicator--active{
  background: #5dc3bd;
  color: #fff;

}

::ng-deep .mat-mdc-tab-labels{
  background: rgb(230,231,232);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;

}

::ng-deep #mat-tab-label-0-0{

  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
```